# Infinite force during head to head elastic collisions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, collision

During head on collisions where the transfer of K.E is instantaneous.

The impulse,

$$∆mv=F×∆T$$

The time of collision is zero here therefore force must be infinite .

Is this correct ? Something doesn't feel right here. Can Infinite force act ?

Comment: When intervals become very small one goes to differentials.F=dp/dt . One never takes differentials to zero.  this might be useful for collisions https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/readings/MIT8_01F16_chapter15.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track.  IF the collision were to happen in zero time, it would imply an infinite force.  In practice no collision is that brief and no force is infinite, but it may be a good approximation in some situations.  More generally, there's no reason to restrict the collision to a short time - it might take place over quite a long time, and the conservation of momentum still applies.  Conservation laws tend to be most useful when we don't know or don't want to deal with the details of the dynamics, like how the collision progresses in time.

Comment: I've understood ,but did the last part imply conservation laws are not applicable during collisions ?

Comment: @Glowingbluejuicebox  Just the opposite - they're particularly useful there, especially when you don't know exactly how the collision proceeds in time or how the force between the objects actually varies with their relative position.

Answer (score 1):

> The time of collision is zero here therefore force must be infinite .
>
> Is this correct ? Something doesn't feel right here. Can Infinite force act ?

You have been tricked by an idealization,
and took it for reality.

In order to make explanations simpler
the colliding bodies are often treated as being infinitely hard.
An infinitely hard body would not deform.
And therefore the collision would happen
in zero time ($\Delta t=0$), and hence the force
would be infinitely high ($F= \infty$) during this time.
But nevertheless, this is not reality, but only a simplifying idealization.

In reality the colliding bodies may be very hard,
but not infinitely hard.
Even billard balls will deform a little bit
(may be some micrometers) during collision.
Therefore the collision takes a very short time
($\Delta t > 0)$, and the force ($F<\infty$)
is very high during this time.

You may want watch this [slow-motion video of golf-balls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TA1s1oNpbk&feature=youtu.be&t=44)
hit by a golf club. Here you can actually see the golf balls
getting deformed a little bit for a very short time.

[image]
<sub>(screen shot from video "[The Moment of Impact. An Inside Look at Titleist Golf Ball R&D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TA1s1oNpbk&feature=youtu.be&t=44)")</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It take a time although small for collision to take place. Although exact variation of $\mathbf{F}$ with time is not known, but it's easy to find the average force in this time interval. For instance, Let the collision time is $\Delta t=t_b-t_a$, the average force
$$\mathbf{F}_{av}\Delta t=\int_{t_a}^{t_a+\Delta t}\mathbf{F}dt=\mathbf{P}_b-\mathbf{P}_a$$

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an elaboration of the conservation part adding to the existing answers. Well, practically time duration of collision is not zero. That's why no infinite force. (Discussed in above answers)

But the momentum is well conserved here, after and before the collision in absence of ground friction. But energy is not conserved. You can explore something that is called COR or Coefficient of Restitution, which is somehow on topic of energy wastage (energy waste causes heat in collision). While the actual time span of collision can be explained by elasticity of colliding bodies.

> Edit

Would like to highlight @Andrew comment:
Rather than saying "energy is not conserved" it is better practice to say "the energy delivered by A is not entirely transferred to kinetic energy of B, some of it goes into other forms such as heat."

Comment: Rather than saying "energy is not conserved" it is better pratice to say "the energy delivered by A is not entirely transferred to kinetic energy of B, some of it goes into other forms such as heat."

Comment: Correct, that will be more precise