Force of impact on a body
This is a pretty silly question which got me pondering for a while.

We know that Force of impact on a body is given by $\frac{m(v_f-v_i)}{t}=\frac{mv_i(e+1)}{t}$ where e is the coefficient of restitution. Now for a bon elastic/non compressible object the force of impact should be infinity(since t becomes 0). So: $$F_i=\frac{mv_i(0+1)}{0}=\inf$$
Does this mean that an incommpressible object will exert an infinitely high force when dropped?


What is “bon elastic”? Did you no”non elastic”?

Close dupe: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592487/infinite-force-during-head-to-head-elastic-collisions

For the case of collision between two perfectly rigid bodies, the forces go to infinity, however, there are no perfectly rigid objects in reality. The rigid body concept is an idealization that was not intended for the analysis of collision forces.

That is a good point about relativity forbidding rigid bodies, i.e. an impulse transmitted to a rigid body travels throughout the body with infinite speed. Rigid bodies are an important theoretical concept, but they shouldn't be taken too literally.

There is no reason that the contact time should go to zero for an incompressible object. Perhaps you mean a rigid object. Superballs are made of rubber that is nearly incompressible and the time spent in contact with the ground during a bounce is certainly not shorter than the time that a billiard ball would spend in contact with the ground for a similar impact.

So in conclusion, every body even rigid ones have a non zero contact time? I cannot correlate to this since contact time depends upon the elasticity of the material. Imagine a billiard ball and a highly elastic ball , Obviously the elastic ball takes a greater time to transfer its energy while a billiard ball takes a much shorter time. Similarly a rigid body will almost take no time in transferring the energy.

No, a "rigid" body is approximated as having zero contact time, infinite contact force, but finite contact impulse. Both a superball and a billiard ball are deformable. All deformable objects, which means all objects, will have a finite contact time.

I believe a non compressible object is an ideal rigid body

Incompressibility is simply the condition that the object cannot change volume, i.e. deformations are isochoric. For isotropic materials there are two elastic constants. These can be chosen to be the bulk modulus $\kappa$ and the shear modulus $\mu$. For incompressible materials the shear modulus can be finite but $\kappa \to \infty$. Fluids are sometimes idealized as incompressible with $\mu=0$ and $\kappa \to \infty$.


Does this mean that an incommpressible object will exert an infinitely
high force when dropped?

A coefficient of restitution of 1 doesn’t mean the objects are  necessarily incompressible, which by definition would make them ideal rigid bodies. It simply means there is no loss of kinetic energy during the collision. The coefficient of restitution for a collision between ideal springs is 1 yet they deform while involving a finite average impact force.
The average impact force experienced by an object during a collision is better described by equation
$$f_{average}=\frac{m\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$
Where $\Delta t$ is the average time of the impact, that is, the duration of the contact time between the colliding bodies.
Of course ideal springs and rigid bodies don’t exist at the macroscopic level.
Hope this helps.

Since $\Delta v = \Delta x/ \Delta t$. The equation can be restated as:
$$\Delta t^2 = \frac{\Delta x} F$$
As the collision time goes to zero, the change in position goes to zero and the Force remains constant.
